# How many iphone devices we an connect via bluetooth or wifi?

Tags: iphone

maximum How many iphone devices we an connect via bluetooth or wifi at a time ?........i need to connect 10...is that possible.......??

Comment: Can you elaborate on what it is you're wanting to connect to or do?

Answer (score 2):

The Bluetooth standard (802.15.1) only allows 7 devices to be connected to a master at once.  If too many are actively communicating, however, the bus can be exceedingly slow.

I'm not sure of the WiFi (802.11b/g) standard, some WAPs say "up to 255" which may be possible, but hilarious to try.  Regardless, 10 is well within WiFi's capabilities.